# Importing app settings from flask blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the following code to load in config variables. What I would now like to do, is use those config variables in the blueprint itself. I think I'm a little hazy on the best way of doing this, so I put this out there.

in my `app.py`

```
app.config.from_object('config')
```

my `config.py` contains:

```
import os
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'xxx/xxx'
ALLOWEDEXTENSIONS = set(['png'])
```

How then in my blueprint should I get for example the `ALLOWEDEXTENSIONS`?

In my blueprint I have:

```
import app as app
mybp = Blueprint('bp', __name__)
print(app.config['ALLOWEDEXTENSIONS'])      # doesn't work
print(app.config.Config.ALLOWEDEXTENSIONS)  # doesn't work
```

How should I deal with importing the global cfg settings and how should I get at the variables?

If I perform `print(app.config)` after `__main__` in `app.py`, it prints my variables, however in the blueprint, when I do the same, these variables are no longer in app.config and hence I'm not able to get at these variables.

In **main**, I can get after printing:

```
<Config {'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False,  'ALLOWEDEXTENSIONS': 'pdf' ....}>
```

But from my blueprint I cannot see all these variables despite importing with `from app import app`:

```
<Config {'JSON_AS_ASCII': True,...}> # None of my variables
```

Answer (score 2):

`current_app.config['...']` should be working

Comment: here is what I get: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'`

Answer (score 2):

You are importing the `app` module, but you need to import the `app` object from that module.

```
from app import app
print(app.config['ALLOWEDEXTENSIONS'])
```

Comment: I have tried this, I modified my question.

Comment: Where exactly you've placed app.config.from_object('config') code in your app.py? And how do you launch it within blueprint file?